# Не создается файл на внешней SD карте

Tags: android, sd

Использую андроид API16. С начала для получения пути к SD карте использовал следующий код `sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`, но мне возвращался путь к внутренней SD. После этого переделал получение пути через файл "/proc/mounts". Путь стал получать правильный. При создании файла 
`File aaa = new File(getSDcardPath()+"/aaa.txt");`
 ни каких ошибок не возникает. Но как только я создаю поток 
`FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(aaa);`
 для записи данных в файл срабатывает исключение FileNotFoundException. После этого попробовал просто создать папку, тоже ни ошибок, ни исключений не появляется. Но и папка не создается. В манифесте прописал следующие разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Может кто уже сталкивался с этой проблемой и нашел решение. Помогите пожалуйста, а то это вроде последняя проблема которая осталась.P.S. Чтением с карта памяти без проблем, все работает

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/index.html#multiple-external-storage-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго искал ответ, НАШЕЛ!!!
Я все делал через plagin ADB для TotalCommander.(Возможно это можно сделать как то еще, не пробовал) Заходим в папку /system/etc/permissions, там ищем файл platform.xml, открываем его для редактирования, в нем находим строку 
`<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >`
 под ней есть строка 
`<group gid="sdcard_rw" />`, ниже добавляем еще одну строку 
`<group gid="media_rw" />`, сохраняем изменения и перегружаем устройство. И о ЧУДО!!! Теперь ваша программа может сохранять файлы на внешнюю SD карту.